# findExportByName finds name which is not in the module

Tags: reverse-engineering, frida

I want to hook the `connect` function for sockets.

First, I need to find its address.

I enumerate the modules with:

```
modules = Process.enumerateModules()
```

What is strange is that

```
addr = modules[i].findExportByName('connect')
```

returns the intended address (which belongs to `libsystem_kernel.dylib` according to `Process.findModuleByAddress(addr)`) for any `i`.

I don't understand how it can work for different values of `i` than the one that corresponds to a module containing the export, and if it really works for all modules, why isn't the `findModuleByAddress` a function of `Process`?

I noticed that

```
Module.findExportByName(null, 'connect')
```

also works but I have no idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are not clear and I'm not been able to reproduce the behavior you described, it works on my phone with the latest Frida ><, still, I'll give it a shot and answer.

`libsystem_kernel.dylib#connect` is the socket connect.

If you pass `null` as the first parameter for `Module.findExportByName` it will search in all modules.

You can use `DebugSymbol.fromAddress` for sanity check.

```
DebugSymbol.fromAddress(Module.findExportByName(null, 'connect'))                                             
{
    "address": "0x185c5c370",
    "fileName": "",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "moduleName": "libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name": "__connect"
}
```

To hook it you can use

`$ frida-trace -Uf com.app -i connect`

or

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, 'connect'), {
  onEnter: onEnterCallback, onLeave: onLeaveCallback
})
```

Comment: there's a missing 'a' in Interceptor.attch

Comment: @Sameh not anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, this works:

```
Module.getExportByName(null,'socket')
"0x183d8ca94"

Process.findModuleByAddress("0x183d8ca94")
{
    "base": "0x183d88000",
    "name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "path": "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "size": 163840
}
```

First, you get the `address` of `socket`. Then you use that address to find the `Module`.

You can shorten these into the command that @i.e. showed. He gave you an excellent answer.

You asked: *"why isn't the findModuleByAddress a function of Process?"*  I am using Frida `"version": "12.11.18"` and it is part of `Process`.